# Converting received array of byte from client to myobject using java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have an issue that when I try to convert array of byte that received from client to an object I got "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". The byte array I received is produced by AES encryption algorithm. notice that my object is implement Serializable interface and I convert the decrypt one .
the code I used for converting is :

```
public MyData toObject(byte[] byt) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Object obj = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        obj = ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (bis != null) {
            bis.close();
        }
        if (ois != null) {
            ois.close();
        }
    }
    return (MyData) obj;
}
```

when I try to send it locally "using localhost"  it works

Comment: Post source code of `MyData` and the object you serialized.

Comment: Is `MyData.class` accessible to the JVM at runtime? That looks like bad deployment.

Comment: this is the MyData object
` import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyData implements Serializable{
    
  private String name; 
  private  String date;
  private String pID;
  private int length;
  
public MyData(String name,String date,String pID,int length){
    this.date=date;
    this.length=length;
    this.name=name;
    this.pID=pID;

}
 //setters and getters
}`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès how I know  if the class is accessible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, it was the class path, they were different on client side and receiver side.

I made them the same package name and it worked :)